# Bayesian Network Meta-Analysis (gemtc)

Tags: r, bayesian

Im trying to conduct a NMA using the R package gemtc. I have three comparisons:
A v D: MD: 119 (17.6)
B v D: MD: 73 (23.98)
C v D: MD: 92 (21.94)

I am following an example code which appear to be functional:

```
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)
library(dmetar)

data(TherapyFormatsGeMTC)

head(TherapyFormatsGeMTC$data)

TherapyFormatsGeMTC$treat.codes
network <- mtc.network(data.re  = TherapyFormatsGeMTC$data,
                       treatments = TherapyFormatsGeMTC$treat.codes)


model <- mtc.model(network,
                   likelihood = "normal",
                   link = "identity",
                   linearModel = "random",
                   n.chain = 4)
```

however when i try and use my code:

```
library(gemtc)
library(rjags)
library(dmetar)

treatments <- read.table(textConnection('
  id  description
  A   "Treatment A"
  B   "Treatment B"
  C   "Treatment C"
  D   "Treatment D"'), header=TRUE)
data <- read.table(textConnection('
  study                 diff         std.err            treatment  
  "Study A"             119          17.60              A          
  "Study A"             NA           NA                 D          
  "Study B"             73           23.98              B          
  "Study B"             NA           NA                 D          
  "Study C"            92           21.94              C          
  "Study C"            NA           NA                 D'), header=TRUE)

data$diff<-as.numeric(data$diff)

network1 <- mtc.network(data, description="Example", treatments=treatments)

model <- mtc.model(network1,
                   likelihood = "normal",
                   link = "identity",
                   linearModel = "random",
                   n.chain = 4)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in validate.data.normal.identity(list(study = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  all(data.ab[["std.err"]] > 0) is not TRUE
```

and I cant work out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

there.
The first argument of `mtc.network` is `data.ab`, which means data for arms other than relative data, whereas the data in both data mentioned are relative data. Thus, it might be helpful if the data can be passed as `data.re` rather than `data.ab` like the following code.

```
network1 <- mtc.network(data.re = data, description="Example", treatments=treatments)
```